# Raspberry pi 3 b+ window IOT stuck at loading (No windows logo)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I installed windows IOT core in raspberry pi 3B+.

It keeps loading on its boot (Windows logo disappears after sometime).
[Loading Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAXKg.jpg)

Though its loading, i can access the the raspberry pi device through windows device portal.

Does any one know a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Go here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot

and download special release for 3B+ (a bit down on the page)

*"RaspberryPi 3B+ Technical Preview Build 17661"*

After having installed this go to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2

and there is a ffu-file which you can use with Windows IoT Dashboard and voilá. It works!

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for windows iot core. At this time,the network is already connected, just not every service is started. Take it easy to use Windows IoT Core.I don't know what did you worry about this issue.

Comment: windows iot core just keeps loading. It doesn't go into the desktop, it just keep loading as shown in the image

Comment: Did you download the image from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot)? Currently, Microsoft only provides  Technical Preview Build 17661 image for RaspberryPi 3B+. Or you can flush the image with another SD card and then test.